# NullPointerException with SQLite-populated Spinner

Tags: android, sqlite, spinner

I've read similar posts on here but I can't get results with those answers.  I'm trying to populate a spinner from SQLite in a custom Dialog but I keep getting a null pointer exception on a particular line

```
    private void showUploadDialog(){

    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MyClass.this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.uploaddialog);
    dialog.setTitle("This is my custom dialog box");
    dialog.setCancelable(true);


    final SimpleCursorAdapter dataSource;
    final String fields[] = { "siteName","_id" };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.spinner_site_item };

    s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

    DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(MyClass.this);
    database = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor ftpCursor = database.query("ftpsites", fields, null, null, null, null, null);
    startManagingCursor(ftpCursor);
    if (ftpCursor != null && ftpCursor.moveToFirst()){
        dataSource = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.spinner_item, ftpCursor, fields, to);

        dataSource.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        s.setAdapter(dataSource);
    } else {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cursor's fucked up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
    database.close();
    Button button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
    //now that the dialog is set up, it's time to show it    
    dialog.show();        
}
```

I get the exception at s.setAdapter(dataSource);

Here's the LogCat output

```
01-24 15:47:08.198: E/AndroidRuntime(10834): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-24 15:47:08.198: E/AndroidRuntime(10834): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-24 15:47:08.198: E/AndroidRuntime(10834):    at app.me.myapp.MyClass.showUploadDialog(MyClass.java:257)
01-24 15:47:08.198: E/AndroidRuntime(10834):    at app.me.myapp.MyClass.access$15(MyClass.java:233)
01-24 15:47:08.198: E/AndroidRuntime(10834):    at app.me.myapp.MyClass$11.onClick(MyClass.java:741)
01-24 15:47:08.198: E/AndroidRuntime(10834):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2532)
01-24 15:47:08.198: E/AndroidRuntime(10834):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9293)
01-24 15:47:08.198: E/AndroidRuntime(10834):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-24 15:47:08.198: E/AndroidRuntime(10834):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-24 15:47:08.198: E/AndroidRuntime(10834):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
01-24 15:47:08.198: E/AndroidRuntime(10834):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4263)
01-24 15:47:08.198: E/AndroidRuntime(10834):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-24 15:47:08.198: E/AndroidRuntime(10834):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-24 15:47:08.198: E/AndroidRuntime(10834):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-24 15:47:08.198: E/AndroidRuntime(10834):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-24 15:47:08.198: E/AndroidRuntime(10834):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-24 15:47:09.559: I/Process(10834): Sending signal. PID: 10834 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

> s = (Spinner) dialog.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

instead of

> s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);